# <apex:outputLink> won't append <apex:param> when the url already contains parameters

Tags: visualforce, outputlink

I have uncovered an unexpected behavior of the `<apex:outputLink>` tag. I am creating an outputlink like so:

```
<apex:outputLink value="/anotherpage?getparam=blah">
    The Link Text
    <apex:param name="apples" value="granny_smith" />
</apex:outputLink>
```

The resulting href of the anchor element is:

```
/anotherpage?getparam=blah%3Fapples=granny_smith
```

This is a very old problem, I found a post from 2009 [here](http://boards.developerforce.com/t5/Visualforce-Development/Using-apex-outputLink-when-value-already-has-a-param-additional/td-p/147138) of someone having the same problem, but no-one had an answer.

Has anyone found a workaround for this? the only idea I have is to ditch the `<apex:outputLink>` and define this as `<a href="...">` in the Visualforce page. But I still have to handle the situation where the outputLink value might not contain a parameter already

Comment: Thanks for the heads up on this. I have your workaround.

Answer (score 5):

I never knew about that bug. It looks like your solution is to either use all `apex:param`, cram all the values into the `value` attribute of the link (that is legal syntax, just remember to use `URLENCODE`), or use a regular link.

```
<apex:outputLink value="/apex/page?a=b&c={!URLENCODE(d)}&e=f">Text</apex:outputLink>
```

I personally advise against using Visualforce elements when a normal, non-Visualforce element will suffice. Note that it *is* useful to use this element for situations like setting a `reRender` target id of the `outputLink`.

**Update** there is a "pseudo-hack" that will work on systems that don't reject unknown parameter names. Here goes:

```
<apex:form >
<apex:outputLink value="/apex/demo?p=1&">
    <apex:param name="=&s" value="2"/>
    <apex:param name="r" value="3"/>
    Hello
</apex:outputLink>
```

This makes the link `/apex/demo?p=1%3F=&s=2&r=3`, which, despite looking odd, is a perfectly legal link (as long as the server doesn't complain about the empty parameter named %3F, or.... "&"). Even salesforce.com itself doesn't notice the parameter if it's in a link.